# Spring MVC 3 form binding

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a simple HTML form:

```
<form id="marketplaceForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<select name="category">
    <option selected ></option>
    <option value="Sales">Sales</option>
    <option value="Marketing" >Marketing</option>
</select>
<textarea type="text" id="marketplaceDesc" name="description" value="" class="creattbleArea"></textarea>
<input type="text" id="marketplaceName" name="templateName" >
<input type="file" id="marketplaceLogo" name="logo">
<input type="submit" value="Save" id="update" />
<input type="text" id="marketplacePrice" name="price">
</form>
```

I need to auto bind this form when I submit it. This works fine:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/.....", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String PublishForm() {
```

But this throws the following error:

HTTP Status 400 - 
The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/PublishApplication.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String PublishForm(@RequestParam("templateName") String templateName,
                           @RequestParam("category") String category,
                           @RequestParam("price") String price,
                           @RequestParam("description") String description
                           ) {
```

Can any one help me?

**Update:** I have found that if I remove `enctype="multipart/form-data"` from the HTML form, it works. Now my question is how to make it work with `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you may be missing the Multipart resolver from your configuration.

do you have something like this in your configuration?

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="250000"/>
</bean>
```

see [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch16s08.html) for the offical spring documentation on the matter.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make sure the binding to `PublishApplication.htm` really works. You are using this mapping in your controller, but you haven't specified it in `action` param of `<form>` tag. So you may end up with posting the form to some different controller, and server rejects your request. Of course this will not happen if you are using the same controller for both - displaying form and submiting it, and you have aplied `RequestMapping` annotation at class level.

There is another issue with your controller though. You are not specifying `logo` as `@RequestParam` in `PublishForm` method. I'm not sure if this is not messing up form autobinding. If I recall correctly, those params are **required** by default.

Comment: I have  found that if i remove enctype="multipart/form-data" from html form. Then it work's. Now my question is that how to make it work with enctype="multipart/form-data" .